# Modyfing a Genbank file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, genbank

Hi i am trying to search through a file for a specific list of words. If one of those words if found i want to add a newline underneath and add this phrase \colour = 1 (I don't want to remove the orginal word i am searching for).

> ```
> An extract of the file for context and format:
> LOCUS       contig_2_pilon_pilon 5558986 bp    DNA     linear   BCT 16-JUN-2020
> DEFINITION  Escherichia coli O157:H7 strain (270078)
> ACCESSION   
> VERSION
> KEYWORDS    .
> SOURCE      Escherichia coli 270078
>   ORGANISM  Escherichia coli 270078
>             Bacteria; Proteobacteria; gamma subdivision; Enterobacteriaceae;
>             Escherichia.
> COMMENT     Annotated using prokka 1.14.6 from
>             https://github.com/tseemann/prokka.
> FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
>      source          1..5558986
>                      /organism="Escherichia coli 270078"
>                      /mol_type="genomic DNA"
>                      /strain="strain"
>                      /db_xref="taxon:562"
>      CDS             61523..61744
>                      /gene="pspD"
>                      /locus_tag="JCCJNNLA_00057"
>                      /inference="ab initio prediction:Prodigal:002006"
>                      /inference="similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:EG10779-MONOMER"
>                      /codon_start=1
>                      /transl_table=11
>                      /product="peripheral inner membrane heat-shock protein"
>                      /translation="MNTRWQQAGQKVKPGFKLAGKLVLLTALRYGPAGVAGWAIKSVA
>                      RRPLKMLLAVALEPLLSRAANKLAQRYKR"
> ```

Here is one of the lists of words i am looking for throughout the file:

```
regulation_list=["anti-repressor","anti-termination","antirepressor","antitermination","antiterminator","anti-terminator","cold-shock","cold shock","heat-shock","heat shock","regulation","regulator","regulatory","helicase","antibiotic resistance","repressor","zinc","sensor","dipeptidase","deacetylase","5-dehydrogenase","glucosamine kinase","glucosamine-kinase","dna-binding","dna binding","methylase","sulfurtransferase","acetyltransferase","control","ATP-binding","ATP binding","Cro","Ren protein","CII","inhibitor","activator","derepression","protein Sxy","sensing","sensor","Tir chaperone","Tir-cytoskeleton","Tir cytoskeleton","Tir protein","EspD"]
```

As you can see that extract contains one of th ephrases i am looking for and i want to add a newline underneath with the phrase `/colour = 1`

Any help would be great!

Comment: You can simply read all lines of your file using `data = open('your_file').readlines()`, then loop over each line, and check if it contains any of your words. If it does, store its location somewhere. Once done add a line containing `/colour = 1` for all positions you stored. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create simple input file for testing:
cat > foo.txt <<EOF
foo
foo anti-termination
bar anti-repressor anti-termination
baz
EOF

python -c '
import re

# Using a shortened version of your list:
regulation_list=["anti-repressor", "anti-termination", "etc"]

# For speed and simplicity, compile the regular expression once, the reuse it later:
regulation_re = re.compile("|".join(regulation_list))

with open("foo.txt" , "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)
        if re.search(regulation_re, line):
           print("/colour = 1")
' > bar.txt

cat bar.txt
```

Prints:

```
foo
foo anti-termination
/colour = 1
bar anti-repressor anti-termination
/colour = 1
baz
```

You may want to add an extra newline and extra blanks to your `/colour=1` string for alignment (it was not clear from you question), like so :

```
print("\n                     /colour = 1")
```